# Change color of selected dynamically added textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to set the background color of a single textbox when I click the mouse button in the textbox. I have an array of boxes, 81 total that i am dynamically adding to the form. I am using var num to name them 1 - 81.
I have been able to get it to work but it adds the color to all of the boxes and not just the one I selected.

```
//array of boxes
TextBox[,] cell = new TextBox[9, 9];

//add boxes to form
for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
{
  for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
  {
   num += 1;
   cell[row, col] = new TextBox();
   cell[row, col].Name = Convert.ToString(num);
  }
}

//handler
cell[row, col].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(cellMouseDown);


public void cellMouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
    {
       //code to add background color to textbox when selected
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a sudoku game.  Use a grid instead.

Answer (score 2):

All though you have other problems, its as simple as this

when creating them

```
for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
{
  for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
  {
   num += 1;
   cell[row, col] = new TextBox();
   cell[row, col].Name = Convert.ToString(num);
   cell[row, col].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(cellMouseDown);
  }
}
```

on click

```
public void cellMouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    var testbox = sender as TextBox;

    if (testbox != null)
    {
        testbox.BackColor = Color.Green; 
    }
}
```

**Additional Resources**

[TextBox.BackColor Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2kh9x59(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to loop through

```
public void cellMouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   var txt = sender as TextBox;
   txt.BackgroundColor = /*to whatever color you want*/
}
```

Also you need to subscribe handler inside loop :

```
for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++)
{
  for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
  {
   num += 1;
   cell[row, col] = new TextBox();
   cell[row, col].Name = Convert.ToString(num);
   cell[row, col].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(cellMouseDown);
  }
}
```